# Get action when press two keys at the same time

Tags: events, html, action

How can I get the action when pressing tow keys at the same time, for example the action when pressing the up and right arrow at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses JQuery but you should get the idea.

```
var down = false, right = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40) down = true;
    if(e.which == 39) right = true;
    if(down && right) {
        alert("Both keys pressed!");
        down = right = false; // required 'cause alert stops 'keyups'
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40) down = false;
    if(e.which == 39) right = false;
});
```